# Using define within cond Racket, knights tour

Tags: expression, racket, depth-first-search, internals, knights-tour

I'm working on an implementation of knights tour using DFS in Racket.

I looked up how to get define to work inside cond, and saw that wrapping define in let would make it work.  But now I get this error:

> `begin` (possibly implicit): no expression after a sequence of internal definitions in: `(begin (define nxn (cons n n)) (define array (for/vector ((x (car nxn))) (for/vector ((y (cdr nxn))) 0))))`

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `define` outside of the top-level is called an internal definition. Internal definitions do not create top/module-level bindings; instead, they're syntactic sugar for an equivalent `letrec*` expression. That means that the bindings created by the internal definitions are visible only within the lambda/scope where the internal definitions live; in your case, that means they are visible only within the `(let () ...)`.

In particular, this means that you cannot conditionally define variables the way you were trying to do in your `cond`. Remember that (since you're already using an imperative programming style) you can just create top-level bindings set initially to `#f` (or some other blank value, though `#f` is customary), and then conditionally `set!` them to the values you want.

Beyond that, there are many other things wrong with your code. For example:

1. Don't compare numbers using `eq?`, use `=`.
2. Don't use parentheses around the `else`; that's invalid.
3. Inside the `else` branch, you had a number of `define` forms that are invalid. Remember you cannot conditionally define new variables.
4. Your `genSuccessors` has *way* too many `cond` expressions. You want to have *one* single `cond` expression with many branches within it. Also you need to break up your branch conditions into multiple lines for easier reading.

Comment: About genSUccessors, if I used 1 cond, and had many branches would it not just generate one successor at a time?  I want to generate all legal successors and add them to a LIFO queue for DFS.                                                              Also when I try to run my program I get error:                           vector-set!: contract violation
  expected: exact-nonnegative-integer?
  given: '(0)
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments...:
   '#(0 0 0 0 0)
   1                                                                       on my first vector-set!

Comment: Looks like I'll have to convert the literal to a number.